# Draggable div get blurred depends on size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create some draggable divs, I have an issue with larger and longer div, it's become blurry when I dragged it. But it's work good with small div.

You can see the example down below , the second div become blurry when you drag.

```css
.item {
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.one {
  height: 20%;
  width: 20%;
}

.two {
  height: 20%;
  width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<div id="items">
      <div class="item one" draggable="true"><header>One</header></div>
      <div class="item two" draggable="true"><header>Two</header></div>
 </div>
```

Ex : Small div on drag
[image: Small div dragged]

Ex : Big div on drag
[image: Big div dragged]

Comment: Firefox here. Both div's on drag gets same opacity and no blur. Can you show images what you see?

Comment: I added some images, even on Firefox i got the same problem

Comment: And these images are from this snippet?

Comment: Yes, they are from the snippet

Comment: can you include your javascript code for dragging?

Comment: There is no dragging functionality in your snippet. Maybe some plugin or extension that changes "build-in-browser" drag visuals?

Comment: I don't have any Javascript code. Even when I try in this example the p tag get blurred. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_global_draggable

Comment: So it seems it's browser stuff. Have you tried some libs like jQueryUI draggabe?

Comment: Not yet, if I found a solution I will post it